# Overwrite option on a standalone ZonalStatisticsAsTable using ArcPy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, zonal-statistics

How can I code an "overwrite option" on a standalone ZonalStatisticsAsTable using ArcPy?

I don't see any overwrite option from a Esri example.

```
# Execute ZonalStatisticsAsTable
outZSaT = ZonalStatisticsAsTable(inZoneData, zoneField, inValueRaster, 
                                 outTable, "NODATA", "MEAN")
```

Is impossible or possible to overwrite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`arcpy.env.overwriteOutput`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00210000001m000000).

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
# Execute ZonalStatisticsAsTable
outZSaT = ZonalStatisticsAsTable(inZoneData, zoneField, inValueRaster, 
                                 outTable, "NODATA", "MEAN")
```

Comment: (in case it's not obvious, note that Jason's answer applies to the whole session, not just to this command)